# How to run program from hidden folder WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm try to run program with this code:

```
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcInfo = { 0 };

    STARTUPINFO StartInfo = { 0 };
    StartInfo.cb = sizeof(StartInfo);

    if (!::CreateProcessW(NULL, (LPWSTR)wszPathToFile, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &StartInfo, &ProcInfo)) {
        return GetLastError();
    }
```

But I get error message: *The system cannot find the path specified.*
wszPathToFile - path to file (example: "C:\test\test.exe /retest"). Folder "test" is hidden
How to fix it?

Comment: That cast makes me nervous.

Comment: szPathToFile - wide char string

Comment: There's no need to cast it.

Answer (score 1):

That the folder is hidden is not relevant. That has no impact here.

As discussed in the comments, the fact that you are casting the `lpCommandLine` argument indicates that `szPathToFile` is not the correct type. It must be a pointer to a modifiable array of wide characters. If it was then you could omit the cast and the compiler would accept `szPathToFile` directly.

Most likely `szPathToFile` is actually a pointer to an array of ANSI encoded 8 bit `char`.

Comment: I using CreateProcessW. This function works with Unicode. Problem is that the directory is hidden. Everything works fine, if the directory is to make visible.

Comment: Clearly you are calling the Unicode function. However, the cast is bogus. That implies that `szPathToFile` has the wrong encoding. The cast cannot change that. It just stops the compiler helping you. Remove the cast. As I said, hidden or not makes no difference. That is, if you mean hidden with `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`. If you are using some nefarious means to hide things then things are different.